# How to run a Nodejs bundled application with Webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I always run my nodejs applications using `node file.js` but after getting my application compiled and bundled using webpack the above command doesn't work, it will print the entire content of the bundled file and then output this error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

The application is written is typescript so here the `ts.config` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

And here is the `webpack.config` file

```
// Generated using webpack-cli http://github.com/webpack-cli
import path from 'path'

export default {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/test.ts',
    output: {
        path: 'D:/asant/Desktop/myproject/bundle',
    },
    plugins: [
        // Add your plugins here
        // Learn more obout plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset',
            },

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as i understand correctly, now your entry file is entry: './src/test.ts'. Moreover6 if u working with node u have a package.json file with script, that describe the logic of running your project

Comment: As I wrote above I'm running it by doing "node bundle/main.js"

Comment: This can now also happen in Node.js as of version 14.

It happens when you declare your package type as module in your package.json. If you do this, certain CommonJS variables can't be used, including require.

To fix this, remove "type": "module" from your package.json and make sure you don't have any files ending with .mjs.